# special characters are not being exported to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jspdf to export the data to PDF. When the data is exported to the PDF, special characters are not displayed in the PDF.

Please find the demo plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/BCgDQm3jV9ctwYJMWkjh?p=preview

In the above demo plunker, when user click on export button, the content is exported to the PDF and PDF is downloaded but issue is i noticed special characters are not being exported to the PDF. The bullets and the numbers mentioned for option1,option2 which can be seen on webpage are not exported to the PDF.

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.export = function() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
    var pdfName = 'test.pdf';

    var options = {};

    var $divs = $('.myDivClass')                //jQuery object of all the myDivClass divs
    var numRecursionsNeeded = $divs.length -1;     //the number of times we need to call addHtml (once per div)
    var currentRecursion=0;

    //Found a trick for using addHtml more than once per pdf. Call addHtml in the callback function of addHtml recursively.
    function recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions){
        //Once we have done all the divs save the pdf
        if(currentRecursion==totalRecursions){
            pdf.save(pdfName);
        }else{
            currentRecursion++;
            pdf.addPage();
            //$('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion] selects one of the divs out of the jquery collection as a html element
            //addHtml requires an html element. Not a string like fromHtml.
            pdf.addHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
                console.log(currentRecursion);
                recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions)
            });
        }
    }

    pdf.addHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
        recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
    });
}
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know how to export these, but it's not characters per se, but [CSS entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). It is not part of the DOM.

Comment: That data is generated by using summernote editor. Is there any way to jsPDF to recognize them?Not sure if jsPDF is the right API to export data to PDF , or is there any better API to use? Its a java application and i'm using angularjs and jQuery. The content is generated by summer note editor.@Kaiido

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [`doc.addHTML`](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML) is being deprecated in favor of a vector able API.
This method indeed seems to lack some features, like the rendering of [CSS `list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).

I am not sure if `doc.fromHTML` is this new API *(currently absent from the docs)*, but it seems to be able to render these :

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML(ul, 15, 15, {
  width: 170
});
doc.addPage();
doc.fromHTML(ol, 15, 15, {
  width: 170
});
var blob = doc.output('blob');
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.width = '100%';
i.height = window.innerHeight;
i.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'doc.pdf';
a.innerHTML = 'download (for chrome...)';
a.href = i.src;
document.body.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="ul">
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="ol">
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

So here is your fixed [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/L0slmcx9szpaXhr7QWZm?p=preview).

Comment: Any css hack to show the highlighted text in the PDF after the data is exported to PDF. https://plnkr.co/edit/GaHLv9SQFwdnzbwZh2y9?p=preview . The highlighted yellow color is not shown in the PDF generated. The same when implemented using .assHTML() https://plnkr.co/edit/LKuwzk5Dt0kdQfMkMfxH?p=preview ,highlighted text is shown but the bullets and numbered options are not shown and the generated PDF is not that clear..@kaiido

Answer (score 0):

As I'm reading at the plugin you used at  [github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12) it appears that you may need UTF-8 charset to do it. you can try to add meta charset UTF-8 on your head html which is you will used it for generate PDF

or if you are using nodeJS as back end. you can try [phantom JS PDF](https://github.com/pofider/phantom-html-to-pdf) . I did used it before and its even supported symbolic language like arabian, chinese, russian, japanese and more (with some configurations)

edited for better readability