# unable to hide the div's for each iteration and want to hide the border being displayed

Tags: javascript, css

When user click on export button, the data is exported to PDF. I'm trying to hide one of the div content while exporting to PDF. 
Below is the code i have used to hide the div content.

```
$("#dontExport1").hide();
```

When the `.hide()` is used data is hidden on PDF and webpage too, so i have used  `$("#dontExport1").show()` after generating and saving the PDF to display the hidden content again on webpage.

Issue is with my code, only first time generated div is hidden, but i have multiple div's generated with `id="dontExport1"`. How to hide all the div's with `id="dontExport1"`.
Second issue is i can see **some border or margin being printed before the first line and after the last line of each page** in PDF, want to hide that border.  Any advice would be helpful.

Please find the demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/81p9MhvGsrSasfUVf1es?p=preview

sample js code:

```
 $scope.export = function() {
   $("#dontExport1").hide();
        var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
        var pdfName = 'test.pdf';

        var options = {};

        var $divs = $('.myDivClass')                //jQuery object of all the myDivClass divs
        var numRecursionsNeeded = $divs.length -1;     //the number of times we need to call addHtml (once per div)
        var currentRecursion=0;

        //Found a trick for using addHtml more than once per pdf. Call addHtml in the callback function of addHtml recursively.
        function recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions){
            //Once we have done all the divs save the pdf
            if(currentRecursion==totalRecursions){
                pdf.save(pdfName);
                 $("#dontExport1").show();
            }else{
                currentRecursion++;
                pdf.addPage();
                //$('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion] selects one of the divs out of the jquery collection as a html element
                //addHtml requires an html element. Not a string like fromHtml.
                pdf.addHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
                    console.log(currentRecursion);
                    recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions)
                });
            }
        }

        pdf.addHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
            recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
        });
    }
```

--Edited---

Please find the image below, i rounded with black for the borders which i want to hide in each page of the PDF generated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to not mix jquery with angular you can use `ng-if` instead of .hide()

Use some flag something like

```
 <div ng-if="!isExporting"><h3><font color="green"> Hide this text in PDF</font></h3></div>
   </div>
```

Then in controller

`$scope.isExporting = true;` when you need to hide this div and `$scope.isExporting = false;` when you need to show.

Also i don't see any border that you mentioned can you highlight that one

[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYYNCeEeD5cLVeoUyVZ6?p=preview)

Comment: Please see my post above, i have added an image where i rounded up the border which is being displayed in every page of PDF. I want to hide it/don't want to show that border in PDF pages.@jitender

Comment: its looks like some pdf reader issue working fine on my side [have a look at this image](http://prntscr.com/h3qa29)

Comment: yes, i am using jsPDF to export the data to PDF. I'm curious as why the same code when ran in your browser is not showing the border whereas i can see it?In this demo https://plnkr.co/edit/tYYNCeEeD5cLVeoUyVZ6?p=preview when you click on export button as PDF is generated, in each page i can see the border.@jitender

Comment: looks strange in which browser you are opening the pdf?may some browser or version issue

Comment: yes its strange. I am using google chrome to test the demo and open the PDF.@jitender

Comment: may be adobe reader setting or some version issue or you can check on some other machine

Comment: ok i will check, thanks for the inputs, accepted the answer. I was actually trying on other issue too. If you can help please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006636/special-characters-are-not-being-exported-to-pdf . As always appreciate your help.@jitender

Comment: As said in above discussion about showing the borders in each page of the generated PDF, i think you have tested only in page1. Borders are shown from page2. Please find the demo plnkr.co/edit/tYYNCeEeD5cLVeoUyVZ6?p=preview  . When clicked on export button, pdf is generated and the borders are shown in every page from page2 of PDF(as shown in the image in my post above).Any inputs would be helpful.@jitender

Answer (score 1):

For why the content is not getting hidden: you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Change

`id="dontExport1"` to `class="dontExport1"`

and

`$("#dontExport1").hide();` to `$(".dontExport1").hide();`

Comment: I cannot give class name as the class name is already assigned and used in multiple places of the webpage.

Comment: @alec I will suggest not to  mix jquery with angular

Comment: @jitender I agree, but in either case, you should not have multiple elements with the same `id`. - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: @user8838953 Having multiple elements with the same `id` is not allowed according to the HTML spec, "The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document)." - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: @user8838953 You can give multiple class names `class="class1 class2"`.

Comment: @AlecFenichel no need to refer to w3school am already knows about it i am only suggesting not to use jquery  here